# Cannot pass mutable reference to self directly

Tags: linked-list, rust, mutability

I am currently working on Rust implementation on Linked List. Before anything, I have read the rust documentation on [Learning Rust With Entirely Too Many Linked Lists](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/first-push.html). But I am still struggling a little bit to understand errors I get when I implement the `into()` trait.

Here is how I implemented it (and it seems to work now):

```rust
impl<T> Into<Vec<T>> for SimpleLinkedList<T> {
    fn into(self) -> Vec<T> {
        let mut res = Vec::new();
        let mut mutable_to_self = self;

        fn into_rec<T>(list: &mut SimpleLinkedList<T>, v: &mut Vec<T>) {
            if let Some(x) = list.pop() {
                into_rec(list, v);
                v.push(x);
            }
        }

        into_rec(&mut mutable_to_self, &mut res);
        res
```

What I am confused about it the need for `mutable_to_self`.
At first, I tried to get rid of this variable and just pass `&mut self` directly to `into_rec()` (To me, this is strictly the same). However, when I do that, I get:

```
error[E0596]: cannot borrow `self` as mutable, as it is not declared as mutable
  --> src/lib.rs:93:18
   |
82 |     fn into(self) -> Vec<T> {
   |             ---- help: consider changing this to be mutable: `mut self`
...
93 |         into_rec(&mut self, &mut res);
   |                  ^^^^^^^^^ cannot borrow as mutable

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0596`.
error[E0596]: cannot borrow `self` as mutable, as it is not declared as mutable
  --> src/lib.rs:93:18
   |
82 |     fn into(self) -> Vec<T> {
   |             ---- help: consider changing this to be mutable: `mut self`
...
93 |         into_rec(&mut self, &mut res);
   |                  ^^^^^^^^^ cannot borrow as mutable
```

So I am unsure what's wrong with the second implementation.

Comment: Is there something you don't understand about the compiler message? You can only borrow mutable variables as mutable and `self` is by default immutable, so either you need to make the function take `mut self` (as is suggested by the compiler) or make a new variable that *is* mutable (as in your original code).

Comment: `self` is not mutable since I passed it as immutable in the inputs. However, I can make it mutable by mutably assigning it to a variable (I guess it makes sense since I own it, but I was still surprised I didn't get any complaint from Rust since I declared it as not mutable). But then it seems weird to me that I cannot pass a mutable reference to an owned variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the owned variables intended to be directly mutable must be mutably bound.

When you declare a variable or an function argument, this could be unified as declaring a *binding* of value to some name - either with keyword `let` or with brackets surrounding arguments list. This binding can be mutable or immutable, depending of presence or absence of `mut` keyword.

If you declare the binding as immutable, i.e. omit the `mut` keyword, the compiler states that you won't acquire the unique reference to it (and hence won't mutate the value, modulo any `UnsafeCell`s inside it). Therefore, if you're trying to get `&mut` reference to it, this is an error.

To fix the error, you can either rebind the variable mutably, effectively discarding the previous binding (if the value is not `Copy`), or bind it mutably at the first place - since this is a part of binding and not of the variable declaration, it can be used the same in function declaration, as well as in the `let` statement.

Comment: That makes sense (I think). So, another thing that worked for me was to change my `into_rec()` function signature with `(mut list: SimpleLinkedList<T>, v: &mut Vec<T>)` and call `into_rec(self, &mut res);`. 
If I understand correctly, this one works because the function definition works as an assignment (it basically does `let mut list = self`), whereas in the other case, I can't do `let list = &mut self` because if assumes `self` is already mutable.